# Jekyll/Liquid - Use a file of navigation items to generate a (ul, li) list and to get properties of the items based on page front matter

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I am using YAML/Jekyll/Liquid to generate a page and I have a file taxonomy.yml which contains "types" of items (this isn't the same as category) and properties of the items.

Here's an example:

```
fruits:
- apple:
    color: red
    size: medium
    native: true
- grape:
    color: green
    size: small
    native: false
```

Now I want to make use of these lists in 2 ways.

1. A ul/li type of list, which should look something like this:

> Types of Fruit
>
> - Apple is **red** and **medium** size
> - Grape is **green** and **small** size

This is what I have so far, but not outputting anything:

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.taxonomy.fruits %}
<li>??? is {{ item.color}} and size {{ item.size }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

2. I want to use the "front matter" property of a given post to 'look up' a value from the navigation list, e.g.

```
---
title: The Pink Lady
fruit: apple
---

# All about the Pink Lady

Blah blah blah...
```

Then based on the fruit (apple in this case) I want to be able to put in the post page, something like this:

> **The Pink Lady**
>
> This article is about a **medium** fruit.
>
> All about the Pink Lady
>
> *Blah blah blah...*

To do this I have to go off to the taxonomy.yml, and look up the "apple" (from the front matter) against the "fruits" list, then read off the "size" attribute (medium in this case) to print to the post.

(Assume the values are unique, so there is only one 'apple' in the file and it will always have a 'size' specified)

This is what I have:

```
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

<p>This article is about a {{ site.data.taxonomy.fruits[page.fruit].size }} fruit.</p>
```

I think I must have failed to understand some detail about working with hierarchies as I believe the idea is basically there but lacking some detail... please help!

I think my misunderstanding may be linked to the distinction between "list items" and "key-value pairs" in some way. I understand those in the abstract but struggling with applying them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably misusing YAML sequences here. Your YAML:

```yaml
fruits:
- apple:
    color: red
    size: medium
    native: true
- grape:
    color: green
    size: small
    native: false
```

says that `fruits` is a list, where each list item is a mapping with a single key-value pair; the key being `apple` or `grape`, and the value being a mapping containing their properties. You probably want to do either of the following things:

#### Option 1: Don't use a sequence.

```yaml
fruits:
  apple:
    color: red
    size: medium
    native: true
  grape:
    color: green
    size: small
    native: false
```

Then you can iterate over the mapping, where `item` will be a tuple of the key and the value:

```html
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.taxonomy.fruits %}
<li>{{item[0]}} is {{item[1].color}} and size {{item[1].size }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### Option 2: Integrate name in properties

Maybe you do want `fruits` to be a sequence. Then you should probably merge the names into the list of properties like so:

```yaml
fruits:
- name: apple
  color: red
  size: medium
  native: true
- name: grape
  color: green
  size: small
  native: false
```

Now you can iterate over the sequence, and `item` will directly contain the list of properties:

```html
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.taxonomy.fruits %}
<li>{{item.name}} is {{ item.color}} and size {{ item.size }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### Yeah but what if I really really want to keep the original YAML

```html
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.taxonomy.fruits %}
{% for kvpair in item %}
<li>{{kvpair[0]}} is {{kvpair[1].color}} and size {{kvpair[1].size }}</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```